# Pricing of Asian Option using R

Tags: r, montecarlo, trading, quantitative-finance

The pricing of the Asian option is approximated, using Monte Carlo simulation, by:

```
delta <- 1/12
T <- 2
S0 <- 100
sigma <- 0.20
K <- 100
r <- 0.01
n <- 10^4
m <- T/delta
S <- S0
for(i in 1:n) {
  for(j in 1:m) {
    W <- rnorm(1)
    Si <- S[length(S)]*exp((r-0.5*sigma^2)*delta + sigma*sqrt(delta)*W)
    S <- c(S, Si)
  }
Si.bar <- mean(S[-1])
Ci <- exp(-r*T)*max(Si.bar - K, 0)
}
mean(Ci)
```

The `for(j in 1:m)` for loop runs perfectly, I think... But when I run it n times, using `for(i in 1:n)` S gets smaller and smaller by n. It decreases to almost zero when n grows. This leads to a mean (`Si.bar <- mean(S[-1])` well below the strike price, K= 100.

I can't figure out what is wrong with the two last lines of codes. I'm getting a value on the Asian call option of 0, due to the payoff function. The correct solution to this option is a value of approximately 7 (`mean(Ci)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, it's inefficient in R to build a vector by repeated concatenation. Instead, you should allocate the vector up front and then assign to its members.

Secondly, as I understand it, the aim is to repeat the inner loop `n` times and store the output into members of a vector `C` before taking the mean. That's not what you're doing at the moment - each iteration of the outer loop makes S longer and overwrites `Ci` such that the last statement, `mean(Ci)` is meaningless.

Here's an amended version of the code. I've used `plyr` partly to make the code neater, and partly for its progress bar functionality.

```
library(plyr)
delta <- 1/12
T <- 2
S0 <- 100
sigma <- 0.20
K <- 100
r <- 0.01
n <- 10^4
m <- T/delta
S <- numeric(m + 1)
S[1] <- S0
asian_price <- function() {
  for(j in 1:m) {
    W <- rnorm(1)
    S[j + 1] <- S[j] * exp((r - 0.5 * sigma^2) * delta + sigma * sqrt(delta) * W)
  }
  Si.bar <- mean(S[-1])
  exp(-r * T) * max(Si.bar - K, 0)
}
C <- raply(n, asian_price(), .progress = "text")
mean(C)

# [1] 7.03392
```

Comment: My apologies for not formulating the problem as clearly as it should while I was in a bit of hurry when writing it.

However, thank you so much! Now it came cleary to me what the problem was. And, yes, the for loop makes it increadibly slow.